# PostgreSQL - PostGIS linkup error

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have a database that I viewed in QGIS using PostGIS.

I managed to link them up using the correst host, database combination last year. I am now revisiting the work and am unable to link them again. The appropriate extentions are installed in Postgres (i use pgadmin), namely postgis and postgis_topology. However when connecting through QGIS it says I cannot connect.

Having had an explore in my postgres database in pgadmin I am recieving the following error when I click on spatial tables:

```
could not load library "/usr/pgsql-9.2/lib/postgis-2.0.so": /usr/pgsql-    9.2/lib/postgis-2.0.so: undefined symbol: pj_get_spheroid_defn
```

The version of postgres is: 9.2.10

When I request the version of postgis the same error message occurs.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like maybe your PostGIS was compiled with a newer proj than what you have installed.  Which proj library did you install with?

Might also just be missing an ldconfig call.